# Simple way to format function names

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am using the default theme in sphinx (1.2.1) and I'd like to have the function names as they appear in headlines (with the args and so on over the function docstring) somehow bigger and better readable like in other themes. Since there are some adaptions I made, **I don't want to switch the theme**.

**Is there any way to achieve this?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that via specifying your own css.  The functions have the css class ".function".  So you can add something like this

```
dl.function dt {
   font-weight: normal;
   [etc ...]
}
```

in your [sphinx dir]/source/_static/default.css .  I usually just make a copy of the original sphinx css file and add my edits at the end.

Similar for

```
dl.class dt,
dl.exception dt,
dl.method dt,
```